# jQuery Accordion expand first enabled panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery Accordion but I have a small problem: Based on some conditions, my accordion could have the first enabled H3 to be the second or third one. The first ones I am disabling by adding this class to them 
"ui-state-disabled".

My accordion looks like this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
         active: true,
         animate: false,
         collapsible: true,
         heightStyle: "content",
         icons: icons
     });
```

Is there a way so that the accordion will only expand the first enabled section? Right now, if I put active: 0 and the first element is disabled, it will expand it nonetheless.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want to make first accordion disabled and not expandable ?

Comment: I can make the first section disabled and not expandable, I want the accordion to auto open the first not disabled section

Comment: Have you tried setting active to first not disabled section, like `active: 1`, something like this https://jsbin.com/giniyan/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be *the most* elegant of solutions, but it'll work. You need to find the index of the first `H3` inside the `#accordion` element that does not have the class `.ui-state-disabled`... so here's that.

You may also realize this already, but you'll want to remove the ability to click to open disabled sections, so I threw that in.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: $('h3:not(.ui-state-disabled):first').index('#accordion h3'),
    animate: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons
});

$(".ui-state-disabled").unbind("click");
```

**[Demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqMVrN)**

edited to add back in your `icons: icons`